# How to remove down arrow icon in dijit.form.dropDownButton?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dijit.form.dropDownbutton in my application. However, I want to remove the down arrow icon in the drop down button. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't do it. It's there because of the various usability conventions - something users come to expect. It points them to a familiar functionality, where a down arrow icon indicates a dropdown box.

Secondly, if you choose to ignore the first advice you can go ahead and do it. The button is controlled by (in case of claro theme):

```
.claro .dijitArrowButtonInner {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(form/images/buttonArrows.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -51px 53%;
}
```

overriding it and adding: `display: none;` removes the arrow and re-sizes the button. You can override it by, for example, assigning an additional class `yourclass` to the `div` and building a paraller CSS hierarchy:

```
.claro .yourclass .dijitArrowButtonInner {
    display: none !important;
}
```

so that in your `<head>` part you have:

```
<style>
    .claro .yourclass .dijitArrowButtonInner {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

and then:

```
<body class=" claro ">
...
    <div id="dropdownButtonContainer" class="yourclass"></div>
...
```

If there is a programmatic way that is simpler than that - I am not aware of it.

**EDIT**
also, as a friendly advice, you should really try and accept answers for your questions, otherwise at some point no one will answer you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The reason I want to remove the arrow is I used dropdownbutton to show descriptions of my form items. Having an arrow next to each form item is not nice looking. (As i am new to dojo, I have not come up with other easy ways for the descriptions.) Also thank you for the kind advice to accept answers. I just figured out how to do so.

Comment: @ZenMaster: I agree that this should be avoided, but sometimes we have custom icons which needs doing this(creating theme might be too much for small set of icons).